# Calculating $Log(-e i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> $$Log(-e i)$$

**My try:**

$$=\ln|0+(-e)i|+i[\arg (0+(-e i))+2\pi k]$$

$$=\ln|e i|+i(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k)$$

My attempt is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$...=\ln(|i||e|)$$

$$=\ln(|i|)+\ln(|e|)$$

$$=\ln(1)+\ln(|e|)$$

$$=0+1$$

$$\Longrightarrow \boxed{1+i(-\frac{\pi}{2}+2 \pi k)}$$

Comment: Why so complicated? $|ie| = e$, so $\ln |ie| = \ln e = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Correct but incomplete. The absolute value of ei is e, and the ln of that is 1.